# How do I plot countplot using the same column from multiple similar datasets?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a ***countplot*** with seaborn using multiple datasets which were sliced from a single dataset( ["heart.csv"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q4jU0SUX82LpCPc8xzZPmbhfuvsnXnVO/view?usp=sharing) ).

I am getting a perfect ***countplot*** using this code below

```
df = pd.read_csv("heart.csv")
df['Sex'].value_counts()
sns.countplot(data=df, x='Sex')
```

But, I need to plot a countplot from different datasets or different segments from a single dataset.
I am slicing the dataset using this code snippet below.

```
Clv = df.loc[0:302, :]
Hng = df.loc[303:(303+293), :]
Swtz = df.loc[(303+294):(303+294+122), :]
Lb = df.loc[(303+294+123):(303+294+123+199), :]
Stl = df.loc[(303+294+123+200):, :]
```

My question is, How do I plot a count subplots from different datasets or from a different segments of a single dataset?

Comment: Put `Clv`, `Hng`, etc. in a list then iterate over it.

Comment: @MattDMo can u elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an extra column, e.g. `'Category'` and assign a value depending on the row index.  Then you can use that new column as a differentiator in seaborn.  E.g. as `hue='Category'` or `x='Category'`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2021)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sex': np.random.choice(['F', 'M'], 1000),
                   'Other_info': np.random.rand(1000)})
df['Category'] = ''
Clv = df.loc[0:302, 'Category'] = 'Clv'
Hng = df.loc[303:(303 + 293), 'Category'] = 'Hng'
Swtz = df.loc[(303 + 294):(303 + 294 + 122), 'Category'] = 'Swtz'
Lb = df.loc[(303 + 294 + 123):(303 + 294 + 123 + 199), 'Category'] = 'Lb'
Stl = df.loc[(303 + 294 + 123 + 200):, 'Category'] = 'Stl'

sns.set()
ax = sns.countplot(data=df, x='Category', hue='Sex', palette='mako')
# an alternative could be x='Sex', hue='Category'
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.countplot using new column]

A `sns.catplot()` using the new column as `col=` could look like:

```py
sns.set()
g = sns.catplot(data=df, x='Sex', col='Category', sharey=True, height=4, aspect=0.5, palette='rocket', kind='count')
g.set(xlabel='')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot using new column as col=]

Answer (score 0):

You should put your resulting dataframes in a list and use a `for` loop to iterate over them one by one. Putting the relevant code in a function also helps you to not repeat yourself.

```
def plot_counts(dataframe):
    dataframe['Sex'].value_counts()
    sns.countplot(data=dataframe, x='Sex')

df = pd.read_csv("heart.csv")
plot_counts(df)

Clv = df.loc[0:302, :]
Hng = df.loc[303:(303+293), :]
Swtz = df.loc[(303+294):(303+294+122), :]
Lb = df.loc[(303+294+123):(303+294+123+199), :]
Stl = df.loc[(303+294+123+200):, :]
df_list = [Clv, Hng, Swtz, Lb, Stl]

for dataframe in df_list:
    plot_counts(dataframe)
```

If you only need to make the `'Sex'` column once, you can eliminate the function definition and just call `sns.countplot()` directly:

```
df = pd.read_csv("heart.csv")
df['Sex'].value_counts()
sns.countplot(data=df, x='Sex')

Clv = df.loc[0:302, :]
Hng = df.loc[303:(303+293), :]
Swtz = df.loc[(303+294):(303+294+122), :]
Lb = df.loc[(303+294+123):(303+294+123+199), :]
Stl = df.loc[(303+294+123+200):, :]
df_list = [Clv, Hng, Swtz, Lb, Stl]

for dataframe in df_list:
    sns.countplot(data=dataframe, x='Sex')
```

Comment: I tried in similar way but got this error "ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence".

I didn't create any function, instead I listed them and iterated over that list using an iterate variable to change the dataframe names and tried t plot them with each iteration but didn't work!

I am getting the same error by copy-pasting ur code snippets below. :(